# Python ThreadPoolExecutor not run max

Tags: python-3.x

I need it to run two threads at the same time. Please help me, i had tried anything i know.

```
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    futures = []
    for k, v in dict_tk_mk.items():
        futures.append(executor.submit(login(k,v)))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VshBg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using wrong syntax of `executor.submit`. It should be like this

```py
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    futures = []
    for k, v in dict_tk_mk.items():
        futures.append(executor.submit(login, *(k,v))) # see this line, you will find the issue
```

For detailed example from where i learnt the syntax, please this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

PS: I made this error when I was new too :P